# while loop using python list

Tags: python, list

```
my_list=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

---

```
i = 10
while i < 10:
   print i ,my_list
   i = i +1
```

My desired output:

```
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
5,5
6,1
7,2
8,3
9,4
10,5
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You probably don't need a while loop: `list(enumerate(my_list*2, 1))`

Comment: Your loop will never run since you start `i` at 10 and loop only while `i` is *less* than 10. I am not sure why you thought that would work. Start `i` where you want to start (1 in this case). You have other problems but those will have clear solutions when you get to them.

Comment: You start with i = 10, therefore you will never enter the while loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
my_list=[1,2,3,4,5]
for index, item in enumerate(my_list*2, start = 1):
    print index,item
```

Answer (score 1):

Your task is what `itertools.cycle` is built for (from Python's standard library):

```
In [5]: from itertools import cycle

In [6]: for i, j in zip(xrange(1, 11), cycle(my_list)):
   ...:     print i, j
   ...:
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 1
7 2
8 3
9 4
10 5

In [7]: for i, j in zip(xrange(12), cycle(my_list)):
   ...:     print i, j
   ...:
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 1
6 2
7 3
8 4
9 5
10 1
11 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in range(10):
    print(x+1,list[x%len(list)])
```

This code is unchecked and you may need to modify it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this easier way :

```
    my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
    newList = (enumerate(my_list*2))
    for num in newList:
        print(num)
```

Output:

```
(0, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
(4, 5)
(5, 1)
(6, 2)
(7, 3)
(8, 4)
(9, 5)
```